# PL/SQL issues returning a sequence scalar value

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to return sequence.nextval to my program from a proc stored in a package.  I'm pretty green when it comes to PL/SQL and I'm kind of at a loss as to what is happening.  The error that is actually being return is

PLS-00306: Wrong number or types of arguments in call to PROCGET_BOOKMARKID line 1, column 7 statement ignored.

Here is my package creation code...

```
create or replace
package BOOKMARKS AUTHID DEFINER is
  type t_Bookmark is ref cursor;

  procedure procGet_Bookmarked_Information(bookmarkId in NUMBER, bookmark out t_Bookmark);
  procedure procInsert_Bookmark(bookmarkId in NUMBER, currExtent in VARCHAR2, selectedLayers in VARCHAR2);
  procedure procGet_Bookmark_Id(bookmarkId out NUMBER);

end BOOKMARKS;
```

And the proc for get_bookmark_id looks like this (the other procs work fine so I'm not going to post them)...

```
  procedure procGet_Bookmark_Id(bookmarkId out NUMBER)
  IS
  BEGIN
    SELECT seq_bookmarks.nextval INTO bookmarkId
      FROM dual;

  END procGet_Bookmark_Id;
```

Now, I'm sure it's not my sequence.  I can get the nextval if I just query the db directly from my code by doing this...

```
string sql = string.Format(@"select {0}.seq_bookmarks.nextval from dual", ApplicationSchema);
```

Where application schema is just the db I'm connecting to in this case.

So, it appears to me that the problem is completely in my PL/SQL and that would make sense because I've hardly used it.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
Ok, so here is the code that is actually making the call.

```
DataOperationResult result = DataAccess.GetBookmarkId();
DataRow currResult = result.DataTableResult.Rows[0];
```

Where DataAccess is a class of just queries and the following is the code there for this specific query.

```
string sql = string.Format("{0}.bookmarks.procGet_Bookmark_Id", ApplicationSchema);
DataOperation operation = new DataOperation(DataOperationType.ExecuteScalar, ConnectionString, System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure, sql);
return operation.PerformOperation();
```

Application Schema is just the database we want to query.  ExecuteScalar is kind of long-winded and it's code I've not written that should be assumed to work (keyword being assumed).  Hopefully this is enough to get an idea of what's happening though.

Comment: Please can we see the code that is calling the procGet_Bookmark_Id?

Comment: Quick check... your error says "PROCGET_BOOKMARKID", whereas your code says "procGet_Bookmark_Id" (with an extra underscore)  Is that just SOF stripping the underscore out?

Comment: working on an edit.  I think it must be just stripping the underscore because nowhere in my code is it called procget_bookmarkid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just compiled your package, in `PL/SQL Developer` it works fine.

The problem seems to be with the datatypes in your `C#` code.

From what I see in description, you don't bind any parameters. You should bind parameters somewhere in your code, like

```
OracleParameter bid = new OracleParameter("bookmarkID", OracleDbType.Number);
bid.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add(bid);
```

If there are lots of abstractions you need to deal with, you may redefine you procedure as a function:

```
FUNCTION procGet_Bookmark_Id RETURN INTEGER
IS
  res INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT seq_bookmarks.nextval
  INTO res
  FROM dual;
  RETURN res;
END procGet_Bookmark_Id;
```

and call it in a `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT bookmarks.procGet_Bookmark_id FROM dual;
```

, which you seem to be able to do.

Comment: You are right, I'm not binding any parameters, I guess I didn't realize I needed to bind output paramaters in my C# code.  Sorry about not posting .net commands, I was just hoping what I posted would be enough, the actual C# commands are behind a ton of abstraction that was written long before me.

Answer (score 2):

The error: "Wrong number or types of arguments in call to blah" refers to errors in the calling code, not the called code.

You should check the following:

- The parameter you're passing is a NUMBER or a type that can be easily converted from a  NUMBER.
- The parameter you're passing is a variable, as opposed to a literal or constant.

Comment: See this is something I'm confused about.  I'm not passing any parameters into the proc.  Should I be?  The query should just be asking for the seq.nextval, does creating it like procedure procGet_Bookmark_Id(bookmarkId out NUMBER); require a number to be passed?

Comment: @Carter: Yes.  If you declare an OUT parameter, you need to pass a parameter from the calling code that will receive the value set by the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to pass in the parameter in your .net code.  The name you give the parameter needs to be identical in the .net code and the procedure definition.

-OR-

Use a PL/SQL function instead of a procedure.  You won't need to use a parameter at all.

Edit: Assuming you are using the Microsoft Provider you will need a return parameter.  Here is the .net code.

```
// proc is the procedure name, oraConn is the oracle connection
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(proc, oraConn);
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

OracleParameter ret = new OracleParameter();
ret.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
ret.OracleType = OracleType.Number;
cmd.Parameters.Add(ret);
```